# Generic method in parent class

Tags: c#, .net

I want a method to exist in the child classes but have different return types. Please view my code below to understand what I am trying to do. Is there a way to accomplish this that anyone knows of?

```
public abstract class MyParent
{
    public abstract T GetStatus();
}

public class MyChild : MyParent
{
    public override StatusEnum GetStatus()
    {
     // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public abstract class MyParent<T>
    where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    public void EnsureTypeIsEnum()
    {
        if(!typeof(T).IsEnum)
           throw new Exception("T must be an enum");
    }

    public abstract T GetStatus();
}

public class MyChild : MyParent<StatusEnum>
{
    public override StatusEnum GetStatus()
    {
     // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

`T : struct` is [a type constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), it prevent you from using a class. Since there's no Enum constraint, this is what you should use (you can add `IConvertible` too, to constraint the Enum type a little more).

If you really need checking if T is an Enum, then you can check it at runtime (I added the EnsureTypeIsEnum method in my answer)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Why do you specify T as inheriting from struct? and how would I do multiple Generics for the same class (I'm mainly confused on how to separate the "wheres")?

Answer (score 0):

the keyword you are looking for should be the "new" keyword, known as "shadows" in vb.net:

```
public new StatusEnum GetStatus()
```

Look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b72ac99f-fd4d-4594-ae1e-813b7f3fae40/vbnet-shadows-keyword-analog-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can either use override on the method in the child class, or have that method return generic object implicitly and cast/convert returned object in the child class anyway you want (if you know what you want returned).